# Is the behaviour of floating-point arithmetic defined by the c++ standard?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I started writing this as a SO question, but I think it's better suited here. While I'm happy for a simple answer I'm also fond of the "Teach a Man to Fish" philosophy so I'm happy for people to point me to documentation.

Is floating-point arithmetic fully locked down by the standard?

In other words, suppose I have a fully compliant c++ program compiled with a fully compliant compiler that performs every possible combination of floating point operation. Will such a program perform identically on any machine with the same data model, regardless of which compliant compiler I use?

Where can I learn more about floating point arithmetic as defined by the C++ standard (I don't have a copy)?

Comment: I believe SO has an excellent answer to this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157094/ieee-float-and-doubles-guaranteed-to-be-the-same-size-on-any-os. The short version is that the C++ standard says almost nothing, but most real-world implementations follow the IEEE 754 standard which is close to being fully deterministic.

Comment: @ixrec: By deterministic, do you mean [consistently irregular](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean there are concrete limits to how irregular any particular operation can be.

Comment: I would believe that a weird implementation where the floating point types are all singleton types (i.e. you have only *one* floating point value, `NAN`) is conformant to the letter (but not the spirit) of the C++11 standard.

Comment: Indeed, C++ standards are costly, but their latest draft is nearly equivalent to them, and you can download them freely, e.g. for [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) download [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: But the practical thing to know is http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Does this mean that a c++ program with floating point arithmetic cannot be defined by the standard?

Comment: It practically means that to understand the semantics of a C++ program dealing with floating point, you need to state that the program is conformant to C++11 and to IEEE754... (practically the case on most C++ implementations). Then I believe that its behavior can be defined (but I am not sure it would be unique).

Comment: No, but you can query and `static_assert` on some models http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777484/how-to-check-if-c-compiler-uses-ieee-754-floating-point-standard

Comment: I think the drafts on [this page (en.cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental) might provide some insights for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard does not fully define floating point behaviour. However, there are floating point standards, like IEEE 754, that are widely supported by C++ compilers (at least among the compilers that support hardware targets that have proper floating point support).

Comment: And C++ provides a way to signal that the IEEE 754 floating-point-standard is in force.